# Ошибка sqlite3.OperationalError, при попытке поставить переменную как название таблицы в sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

В моем проекте нужно чтобы при изменении переменной ID создавалась новая таблица, поэтому я пытался вставить переменную в качестве названия таблицы

```
import sqlite3

conn=sqlite3.connect('tb.db')
cur=conn.cursor()
ID=2304829445
cur.execute('''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {0}'''.format(ID))
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE {0} (name TEXT, age INTEGER)'''.format(ID))
cur.execute('''INSERT INTO {0} (name, age) VALUES('anton', '12')'''.format(ID))
conn.commit()

print('mytable:')
cur.execute('''SELECT name FROM {0}'''.format(ID))
Name=cur.fetchone()[0]
cur.execute('''SELECT age FROM {0}'''.format(ID))
Age=cur.fetchone()[0]
print(Name, Age)
```

но при выполнении этого кода мне выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Q:\python\p\code.py", line 6, in <module>
    cur.execute('''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {0}'''.format(ID))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "2304829445": syntax error
```

что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Названия объектов в SQL должны **начинаться** с буквы или символа подчеркивания.

Поэтому вы получаете ошибку синтаксиса.

---

Вот [выдержка из стандарта ANSI SQL-92](https://docs.actian.com/ingres/11.0/index.html#page/CharQueryRepUser/Object_Naming_Conventions_for_ANSI_2fISO_Entry_SQL.htm):

> ### Object Naming Conventions for ANSI/ISO Entry SQL-92 Compliant Databases
>
> For reports based on tables or views in ANSI/ISO Entry SQL‑92
> compliant databases, observe the following conventions regarding
> object names when referencing them within Report-Writer statements and
> commands:
>
> - Names consist of 18 or fewer characters.
> - Regular identifiers begin with an alphabetic character (`a` ‑ `z`) and contain only alphabetic, numeric, or underscore (`_`) characters.
> - Regular identifiers are case insensitive.
> - Delimited identifiers are case sensitive.
>
> These conventions differ somewhat from standard Ingres conventions for regular and delimited
> identifiers. Also, in standard Ingres databases, regular identifiers
> can include the non‑alphanumeric characters `#`, `@`, and `$`, and
> delimited identifiers can be case insensitive, depending on how the
> database was created.